# Rxjs - unexpected publishReplay + refCount behaviour after refCount goes to 0

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

My usecase is this: I connect to a service with a websocket and get periodic (but unpredictable) health data from the service.  The app may have multiple users of this data stream, so I want to share it.  New subscribers should see the most recently emitted health data.  I also want to close the websocket when there are no more subscribers.

My app used `shareReplay(1)` for quite some time, until it was discovered that it leaks the underlying connection (https://blog.strongbrew.io/share-replay-issue/).  At which point we changed to `pipe(publishReplay(1), refCount)`.  It turns out that this also has a subtly that I did not expect:

1. Subscriber A connects & the websocket connection is established.
2. Subscriber B connects and shares correctly, as well as getting the most recent data.
3. Both A and B disconnect.  The websocket is torn down
4. Subscriber C connects, but only needs one value `take(1)`.  The value that is cached by the `publishReplay(1)` is returned.

In step 4 I really wanted the websocket to be re-created.  The cached value is of no use.  The timewindow parameter of `publishReplay` is tempting, but also not quite what I want.

I've managed to find a solution, by using `pipe(multicast(() => new ReplaySubject(1)), refCount())`, but I don't know Rx well enough to understand the full implications of this.

My question is - what's the best way to achieve the behaviour I want?

Thanks!

Code sample can be seen at https://repl.it/@bradb/MinorColdRouter
Inline code

```js
    const { Observable, ReplaySubject } = require('rxjs');
    const { tap, multicast, take, publishReplay, refCount } = require('rxjs/operators');
    
    const log = console.log;
    
    function eq(a, b) {
      let result = JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b);
      if (!result) {
        log('eq failed', a, b);
      }
      return result;
    }
    
    function assert(cond, msg) {
      if (!cond) {
        log('****************************************');
        log('Assert failed: ', msg);
        log('****************************************');
      }
    }
    
    function delay(t) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
      });
    }
    
    let liveCount = 0;
    
    // emitValue 1 happens at 100ms, 2 at 200ms etc
    function testSource() {
      return Observable.create(function(observer) {
        let emitValue = 1;
        liveCount++;
        log('create');
        let interv = setInterval(() => {
          log('next --------> ', emitValue);
          observer.next(emitValue);
          emitValue++;
        }, 100);
    
        return () => {
          liveCount--;
          log('destroy');
          clearInterval(interv);
        };
      });
    }
    
    async function doTest(name, o) {
      log('\nDOTEST: ', name);
      assert(liveCount === 0, 'Start off not live');
      let a_vals = [];
      o.pipe(take(4)).subscribe(x => {
        a_vals.push(x);
      });
      await delay(250);
      assert(liveCount === 1, 'Must be alive');
    
      let b_vals = [];
      o.pipe(take(2)).subscribe(x => {
        b_vals.push(x);
      });
      assert(liveCount === 1, 'Two subscribers, one source');
      await delay(500);
      assert(liveCount === 0, 'source is destroyed');
      assert(eq(a_vals, [1, 2, 3, 4]), 'a vals match');
      assert(eq(b_vals, [2, 3]), 'b vals match');
    
      let c_vals = [];
      o.pipe(take(2)).subscribe(x => {
        c_vals.push(x);
      });
      assert(liveCount === 1, 'Must be alive');
    
      await delay(300);
      assert(liveCount === 0, 'Destroyed');
      assert(eq(c_vals, [1, 2]), 'c_vals match');
    }
    
    async function main() {
      await doTest(
        'bad: cached value is stale',
        testSource().pipe(
          publishReplay(1),
          refCount()
        )
      );
      await doTest(
        'good: But why is this different to publish replay?',
        testSource().pipe(
          multicast(() => new ReplaySubject(1)),
          refCount()
        )
      );
      await doTest(
        'bad: But why is this different to the above?',
        testSource().pipe(
          multicast(new ReplaySubject(1)),
          refCount()
        )
      );
    }
    main();
```

Comment: `pipe(multicast(() => new ReplaySubject(1)), refCount())` and for an explanation you can read [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-how-to-use-refcount-73a0c6619a4e) and perhaps [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-the-publish-and-share-operators-16ea2f446635) too.

Comment: Thanks @cartant.  I've read those articles before, but still don't really 'get it'.  What exactly is happening that makes the `multicast(...)` solution work?  I expect my mental model is out of whack with reality somewhere.  It seems to me that this sort of lifetime management is where 90% of the conceptual complexity of Rx hides.

Comment: When a factory is passed to `multicast`, the existing subject will be unsubscribed from the source and discarded whenever the ref count hits zero. Then, if another subscription is later made, a new subject will be created and subscribed to the source. The `publish` variants *do not* pass a factory to `multicast` - that's how they differ from the `share` variants.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing the comment from cartant:

`publishReplay` will use **a single ReplaySubject** under the hood, which is un- and then re-subscribed by `refCount`. Therefore its cached value is replayed. When you use `multicast` with a factory, a new ReplaySubject is created each time `refCount` un- and then re-subscribes - therefore, no cached value.

Here are cartant's links, as the ones in the comment are not reachable:

- https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-publish-and-share/
- https://ncjamieson.com/how-to-use-refcount/

From the article:

> The multicasting infrastructure’s subject is able to be re-subscribed.

`publishReplay` uses `multicast` under the hood and does not provide a factory, but re-use the same ReplaySubject.